Restoring Database neo4j in Docker container from .backup file
I have a Dockerfile that uses the official Neo4j Enterprise image and restores a database from a backup. When I restore the database, it is visible in the /data/databases directory. The name of the database is piqosity. However, when I go to the Cypher shell and execute the command SHOW DATABASES, it only shows the default neo4j DB and system DB, but not piqosity.
I found a solution where I go to the Cypher shell and execute the command CREATE DATABASE piqosity. When piqosity is created, it is available there and has all my piqosity data. Now, I want to add the steps for creating the piqosity database into the Dockerfile so I don’t have to go to the Cypher shell every time and execute the command to create the database.
Here is my Dockerfile:
# Use the official Neo4j Enterprise image as the base image
FROM neo4j:enterprise

# Set the environment variables for Neo4j
ENV NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/Tahir@0308

# Copy the database backup file into the container
COPY neo4j-2024-05-23T00-06-33.backup /backup/

# Change the ownership and permissions of the backup directory
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat \
  && chown -R neo4j:neo4j /backup \
  && chmod -R 755 /backup

# Run the restore command using neo4j-admin as the neo4j user
USER neo4j
RUN neo4j-admin database restore --from-path=/backup/neo4j-2024-05-23T00-06-33.backup --overwrite-destination=true piqosity

# Expose the default Neo4j ports
EXPOSE 7474 7687

# Start Neo4j and wait for it to fully start
CMD neo4j start && \
  sleep 120 && \
  cypher-shell -u neo4j -p Tahir@0308 'CREATE DATABASE piqosity;' && \
  tail -f /dev/null

However, when I add these lines:
CMD neo4j start && \
  sleep 120 && \
  cypher-shell -u neo4j -p Tahir@0308 'CREATE DATABASE piqosity;' && \
  tail -f /dev/null

I get an error: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
There is no issue with the credentials because when I remove these lines from the Dockerfile (which are creating the database) and build the container, I’m able to log in to the Cypher shell with the same credentials without any issue.
I want to create a database in Neo4j within the Dockerfile. Or, if there is any solution, I can restore my database in the Docker container and it will run fine and be visible when I run the SHOW DATABASES command or when I access it at localhost:7474.
I have tried changing the Dockerfile and also tried to do the database creation steps with a shell script, copied it into the container, and run it so that if CMD is not able to run the commands, the script can do it. But no luck.

As the Neo4j server never started so far, the NEO4J_AUTH env was never used and thus the initial password not set yet.
You will need to set it before running the cypher shell command
# Set the initial password
RUN neo4j-admin dbms set-initial-password Tahir@0308

# Start Neo4j and wait for it to fully start
CMD neo4j start && \
  sleep 120 && \
  cypher-shell -u neo4j -p Tahir@0308 'CREATE DATABASE piqosity;' && \
  tail -f /dev/null


Yeah The Issue is Resolve by Setting initial password  Thank You so much for you help.

Remember that any ENV variables and RUN commands are visible in docker history to anyone who has a copy of the image – it is all but trivial to recover this password.
