Neo4J docker-compose cypher-shell: unauthorized due to authentication failure
I am trying to get my neo4j v4.1 database running in a docker container with docker-compose. Here are my files:
docker-compose.yml
services:
  neo4j:
    build: .
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"  # HTTP port
      - "7687:7687"  # Bolt port
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
      - ./plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/mypass 
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes

Dockerfile
FROM neo4j:4.1-enterprise
# Copy your initialization scripts into the container
COPY scripts /var/lib/neo4j/scripts
RUN chmod +x scripts/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/var/lib/neo4j/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Start Neo4j in the background
neo4j start

# Wait for Neo4j to be ready
echo "Waiting for Neo4j to start..."
sleep 15

echo "Testing cypher-shell authentication..."
cypher-shell -u neo4j -p mypass "RETURN 1;"

neo4j stop

# Start Neo4j in the foreground
neo4j console

I run with docker-compose and get the following lines in my logs:
neo4j  | Testing cypher-shell authentication...
neo4j  | The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

I have tried to turn authentication off with setting NEO4J_AUTH=none. I also tried setting Neo4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4j but I get the same authentication error. I have tried deleting files out of the ./data folder and running docker-compose build with the --no-cache flag.  There doesn't seem to be errors in /var/lib/neo4j/logs/debug.log.
In addition when I navigate to https://localhost:7474/ I get a page with the following:
This site can’t be reached
localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

How do I fix this authentication error?

Probably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78533845/restoring-database-neo4j-in-docker-container-from-backup-file/78534075#78534075

You may have other problems, but this line in your Dockerfile is specifying the wrong path:
RUN chmod +x scripts/entrypoint.sh

Use this instead:
RUN chmod +x /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/entrypoint.sh


Thanks for the recomendation. I did have that. I was experimenting with how the entrypoint.sh was handled. Both ways seem to work, but having a global path is probably better practice.
